# How to understand this recursive result

Tags: function, go, recursion

I wrote a bug while coding, when I solved the problem, I was confused about the output of the code,the code show as below:

```
type (
    Handler func(name string) error
)

func mh(h Handler) Handler {
    return func(name string) error {
        fmt.Printf("return mh,name=%s,h=%x\n", name, h)
        return h(name)
    }
}

func main() {
    var h Handler
    h = func(name string) error {
        fmt.Printf("********************************\n")
        fmt.Printf("before func h=%x\n", h)
        h = mh(h)
        fmt.Printf("after func h=%x\n", h)
        return h(name)
    }
    fmt.Printf("main h=%x\n", h)
    h("main")
}
```

Running the code, the output is:

```
main h=486d40
********************************
before func h=486d40
after func h=486c00
return mh,name=main,h=486d40
********************************
before func h=486c00
after func h=486c00
return mh,name=main,h=486c00
return mh,name=main,h=486d40
********************************
before func h=486c00
after func h=486c00
return mh,name=main,h=486c00
return mh,name=main,h=486c00
return mh,name=main,h=486d40
.......
```

I don't understand the call stack.I thought the output should be loop "mh".

Comment: It'd be worth while stepping through this with delve, and maybe check the disassemble output, too. That should make things clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key thing to understand is that this line:

```
h = mh(h)
```

Does **not** call the `h` function. It calls the `mh()` function, which just returns a function value, but it does not call `h()` either. If the returned function value would be called, that would call `h()`.

So the `main()` function stores a function value in `h`, then calls `h()`.

This `h()` prints `"before"`, then *wraps* `h` in another function, and stores the result in `h`, then prints `"after"`. It's important to know that the wrapper function (the value returned by `mh()`) is a closure, and it stores the original value of `h`, so assigning the result to `h` does not affect the `h` inside the wrapped function.

So `h` ends by calling `h` which is now the wrapped function. The wrapped function starts by printing `"return"`, then it calls the original, unwrapped `h`.

The original, unwrapped `h` again prints `"before"`, then it wraps the current value of `h` (which is the wrapped function), stores it in `h`, then prints `"after"`.

And then calls `h`, which is now a 2-times wrapped function. It starts by printing `"return"`, then calls the saved `h` value, which is a 1-time wrapped function. The 1-time wrapped function starts by printing `"return"` (again), then proceeds with the original one, which prints `"before"`, wraps `h` which will now be 3-times wrapped, stores it in `h`, then calls `h` (which is the 3-times wrapped function value)...

This logic continues, the function value stored in `h` will become wrapped more and more, and the wrapped function always has a saved value of the one-less times wrapped previous function.

As the "iteration" continues, the "wrapping depth" increases, therefore you'll see more and more `"return"` statements printed (as that's what the wrapping does).

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is this assignment:

```
  h = mh(h)
```

It replaces the binding of `h` in `main` from the anonymous function that prints out before/after to whatever `mh` returns.

If you replace

```
    h = mh(h)    
    fmt.Printf("after func h=%x\n", h)    
    return h(name)
```

With

```
    return mh(h)(name)
```

You will get the mutual recursion you expect

Comment: when I use `h = mh(h)`, Why is mutual recursion happening?